# Can PHP's symlink() create a relative symbolic link?

Tags: php, symlink

If I want to create a symbolic link in PHP I can use the `symlink()`-command. However, I can only seem te create absolute links using this method. For example:

If I do `ln -s ../bar ./bar` in `path/to/foo` a relative symbolic link to `../bar` is created in `pat/to/foo`. Now If I try to achieve the same thing in PHP:

```
symlink('path/to/foo', '../bar')
```

It does not create a symlink pointing to `../bar` in `path/to/foo`. I also tried:

```
chdir('path/to/foo');
symlink('../bar', './bar');
```

But also with no success. Can relative symbolic links be created using native PHP?

Comment: I can create relative symlinks from Php.  Argument order matters.

Comment: First the target, then the link name (as in `bool symlink ( string $target , string $link )`) Neither `../bar` nor `./bar` are not valid names for the link

Comment: `'./bar'` and `'../bar'` as the link argument works on my system.

Comment: Do you have write access to the write access to the target dir? Also I did some testing in php's interactive terminal. I could create a link. Then I went to a different terminal and deleted the link. I count not create the link in the interactive terminal. Php thought the file was still there. If I was in the same php terminal I could create, delete, then create the link without a problem.